# About a probability function

Tags: probability

**Problem**
Given the sample space *S={1,3,5,...}* formed by all the odd positive numbers, it's defined the probability

$P\left(\left\{i\right\}\right)=k\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i\:,\:i=1,\:3,\:5,...$

a)Find k such that *P* is a probability function.

b)Find the probability of the event A={7, 9, 11,...}

**My reasoning**

a)it's quite clear that $P\left(\left\{i\right\}\right)\ge 0$
so for making it a probability function I evaluate the
$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\:k\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i=k\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{i-1}=k\left(\frac{1}{\frac{3}{1-\frac{1}{3}}}\right)=\frac{k}{2}$
equal to 1 is $\frac{k}{2}=1$ so $k=2$

In that way
$P\left(\left\{i\right\}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i\:,\:i=1,3,5...$ is a probability function.
I think that's correct but I would like some confirmation hehe.

b) Here is where I'm having some troubles.
I think it can be define as
$P\left(i\in \left\{7,9,11,\:...\right\}\right)=\sum _{i=7}^n\:2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i$
But I'm not sure if this is ok or how to handle that series.

I thought that also the probability of that event could be found using the compliment of a probability but still haven't figured out on how to manage it properly.

Comment: You have both parts wrong. Hint: $kp^1+kp^3+kp^5+kp^7+...=kp^1(1+p^2+p^4+p^6+...)=kp(1+(p^2)^1+(p^2)^2+(p^2)^3+...)$

Answer (score 1):

@r.e.s.

Yes I'm noticing the first mistake

$Sn=kr+kr^3+kr^5+...+kr^{2i-1}$
$r^2Sn=kr^3+kr^5+kr^7+...+kr^{2i+1}$

$Sn=\frac{kr}{1-r^2}$

$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\:k\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i\:,\:i=1,3,5...$ $=k\left(\frac{1}{\frac{3}{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2}}\right)=\frac{k3}{8}$

so is a probability function if $k=8/3$

$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{8}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i\:,\:i=1,3,5...$

Now for the (b) part, can this be a way to evaluate the probability of that event?

$P\left(i∈7,9,11,...\right)=\sum _{i=7}^n\:\frac{8}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^i\:$

or maybe just calculating the probability to the first 3 (1,3,5) and applying the compliment to that.